# ArrayList change all objects one property value

Tags: java, list, collections

Java Spring Collection

```
List<CustomObject> myList = new ArrayList<CustomObject>(1000); // list with thousnda objects
```

i want to set CustomObject property 'type' of all objects in the list. Simple way is running a loop and set property as following.

```
for(CustomObject obj:myList){
obj.setType('value'); 
}
```

I want to make code look nicer little bit so if there is any other way doing the same thing in one line of code?

Comment: That code looks nice. Probably you want one line, that can be achieved by using Java 8.

Comment: I feel like "looking nice" is super-subjective here. I would not consider that bad-looking code by any stretch.

Answer (score 12):

In Java 8 :

```
myList.forEach(c -> c.setType("value"));
```

Comment: I am using Java 7, any other solution ?

Comment: @Faisalkhan Your current solution with the enhanced for loop is probably the best you can do with Java 7.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Guava Collections](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CollectionUtilitiesExplained):

```
List<CustomObject> initializedList = Lists.transform(myList, new Function<CustomObject, CustomObject>() {
    @Override
    public CustomObject apply(CustomObject obj) {
        return obj.setType("value");
    }
});
```